# don't need iCloud storage any longer

Tags: iphone

I have a phone now that has more storage, how do I remove what I have stored in iCloud storage?  I don't need to continue paying monthly

Comment: You want to 'remove' or download everything you have?  I ask because iCloud is a sync solution so whatever you delete from there will be gone for good (from every device) unless you save it somewhere.

Comment: yes, I had 8gbs and now have 32 so I have room on this phone to put whatever I have in storage.. I can't even find how to find out what I do have storage there

Comment: I only have like 1.5gb on storage..very little

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all photos, documents, data or disable iCloud library for your account.  Proceed like follow:

On iOS10:
Go to **Settings > [your_name] > iCloud > Storage > Manage Storage** from there you can disable, delete everything you want.

For iCloud Photo library, you'll have 30 days to download everything stored there.

Update:
To download your photos and videos on your iOS device, go to **Settings > [your name] > iCloud > Photos** and select **Download and Keep Originals.** On your Mac, open **Photos,** choose **Photos > Preferences**, then select **Download Originals to this Mac**. 
You can also select the photos and videos that you want to download from [iCloud.com](https://icloud.com).

Further informations can be found [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204570).

Comment: thank you ...but how do I download what is there back on my phone? I don't even know what is stored there? sorry, if that sounds dumb....

Comment: thank you.. I only had 1 gb there so and I have all my photos on the phone.. so I apparently didn't lose much.. thanks anyway guys!

Comment: Updated my answer.